# Async Nodejs API delays first request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, asynchronous

I am creating an API for a hobby of mine and I ran into an issue where my server responds to my second request before my first because my first request is more computational intensive than the second but I want to get the result of the first request first, now I tried using it in the synchronous way but then when one client is using the service others will stall and I do not want that either. so my question is whether there is some pattern I should follow or have a FIFO stack in my server for every client that connect to solve this or any other better way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: I'd highly suggest posting your script here, or atleast the portion of the script that's causing issues. This is 100% an asynchronous issue.